# iPad 2 asks to connect to iTunes while iTunes asks for passcode on iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, software-update

**SCENARIO:**

I have an old iPad 2 (*I think*) model A1396 from a relative reclaiming an iTunes update. iPad screen is telling device is deactivated and should be connected to iTunes.

[image]

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I downloaded iTunes and connected the iPad, iTunes detects the iPad, but complains because I need to put the passcode in the iPad.

[image]

**PROBLEM**

I have the passcode, but the iPad screen is not asking for it, I can't unlock the screen and I just can restart the iPad, entering in this way in a vicious circle… *sigh!*

**QUESTION** is: Is there some way to unlock the iPad to insert passcode and allow update via iTunes?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the reason the iPad is disabled and requires you to connect to iTunes to re-activate it is because the passcode was entered incorrectly too many times.

In this case, you'll need to erase the iPad, and unless you made a backup before the iPad got disabled, there isn't a way to save your device's data, and you'll lose all your data and settings.

**Erase your device with recovery mode:**

If you've never synced with iTunes or set up Find My iPhone in iCloud, you'll need to use recovery mode to restore your device. This will erase the device and its passcode.

1. Connect your iOS device to your computer and open iTunes.
2. While your device is connected, force restart it: Press and hold the Sleep/Wake and Home buttons at the same time. Don't let go when you see the Apple logo — keep holding until you see the recovery mode screen.

   [image]
3. When you see the option to Restore or Update, choose Restore.

   [image]

   iTunes will download software for your device. If it takes more than 15 minutes, your device will exit recovery mode and you'll need to repeat steps 2 and 3.
4. Wait for the process to finish. Then you can set up and use your device.

For more info, check Apple's support [article](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204306).

Comment: mmm... must be this for sure? I already found that googleing, but my uncle (iPad's owner) didn't tell me nothing about failing several times passcode, he does not have computer and he gives me the code to unlock when connected to itunes.....

Comment: I think I'm sure, especially after you posted that screenshot. Your uncle may have forgotten to mention failing several times. He also doesn't need to have a computer for this to happen.

Comment: Sure, failing several times could happen without computer.... I guess he didn't notticed (little cousins around).... Also bad part... no computer... no backup.... *grgrggrrrrrrrr*

Comment: Screenshot is from internet, iPad is complaining in Spanish, but is almost same, and message is exact... so I guess you're right

Comment: I called him and confirms, he didn't failed with passcode... there is another possibility around?

Comment: @JordiCastilla I'm sorry man I can't help more than that! And if you ever get convinced that that's the case, please mark this answer as the correct one.

Comment: Sure, let me check a bit more, im aware of how stackexchange forums works ;)

Comment: We've found the problem... iPad screen wasnt calibrated and my little cousin tried to put the passcode failing several times! Now iPad is restored via iCloud and working! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @JordiCastilla I'm glad you were able to restore it via iCloud!